# Determining the PID from a call to popen on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, popen

If I attempt to close the pipe while it's running, it waits until the command is finished. Some commands runs forever causing it to freeze infinitely. The only solution I've managed to come up with is to determine the PID, terminate the process and then close the pipe. But I haven't found a way to determine the PID safely.

```
FILE* pipe;
wchar_t* command;

pipe = _wpopen(command, L"r");   
... // determine the PID and TerminateProcess
pclose(pipe);
```

So how do I determine the PID from a call to popen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to get the `pid`. Use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` or `EnumProcesses` to get a list of `pids` and chose yours.

Here is some [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerates processes. [Some more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This is the same solution I'm using right now (by comparing the process command) but it feels cheap. There must be some other way. Maybe by using a diffent function instead of popen.

Comment: @Michael  You can code your own popen - crt sources are shipped with Visual Studio - you can tweak that a little and created a modified mypopen which returns the PID/Handle which comes from CreateProcess. Other than that, I can't think of another way.

Comment: I will definitely look into that. Thank you!